How to re render cards in a swiper using react-native-deck-swiper
I'm facing an issue with updating the content of cards in a swiper using react-native-deck-swiper. I have a button external to the swiper, and when pressing it I want to update the content of the current card and trigger a re-render to reflect the changes.
I've managed to update the state of the item correctly, but the card doesn't re-render immediately. It only renders again when I start swiping the item.
The documentation suggests a possible fix, stating, "A possible fix for the situation is setting the cardIndex on the parent component whenever deck re-renders are needed." However, my attempt to implement this hasn't been successful.
I have noticed that the change is render when the overlay condition are required (even if no overlay is set).
Below is a reproducible example of the problem :
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-deck-swiper';

const cards = [
    { color: 'red', updated: false },
    { color: 'blue', updated: false },
    { color: 'green', updated: false },
    { color: 'yellow', updated: false },
    { color: 'purple', updated: false },
];

export default function App() {
    const [cardIndex, setCardIndex] = useState(0);
    const swiperRef = useRef(null);

    const updateCard = () => {
        cards[cardIndex].updated = !cards[cardIndex].updated;
        // Force re-render??
        setCardIndex(cardIndex); 
    };

    const onSwiped = () => {
        setCardIndex((cardIndex + 1) % cards.length); 
    };

    const renderCard = (card) => (
        <View style={[styles.card, { backgroundColor: card.color }]}>
            {card.updated && <Text style={styles.updatedText}>UPDATED</Text>}
        </View>
    );

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Swiper
                ref={swiperRef}
                cards={cards}
                renderCard={renderCard}
                onSwiped={onSwiped}
                onSwipedLeft={onSwiped}
                onSwipedRight={onSwiped}
                cardIndex={cardIndex}
                infinite
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={updateCard}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Update card</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    card: {
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
      },
    updatedText: {
        position: 'absolute',
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'black',
    },
    button: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 20,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
});

I'd appreciate any insights on how to solve this issue and get the card to re-render immediately upon pressing the button. Thank you!

They have something in their docs about this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-deck-swiper#updating-props-on-card-content-dynamic-card-content

@DevonRay Yes they are saying something about it in the documentation (that I am quoting in my question) but it does not seems to work from my comprehension of it.

you were setting it back to cardIndex though, needs to change for it to work +1 or somehting

At first, I thought the issue was that you werent storing the cards in a state variable, but after doing so, I found that the cards still wouldnt update, which makes me believe that Swiper component caches card on initialization and ignore all updates to it. This where the key prop comes to play. A component will be reinitialized when its key changes, so if you store the swiperKey in state and the update it, cards will be reinitialized (demo):
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-deck-swiper';



const getRandomInt = (min=0,max=1)=>{
  const range = max - min
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*range)+min
}

const initialCardState = [
  { color: 'red', updated: false, },
  { color: 'blue', updated: false, },
  { color: 'green', updated: false, },
  { color: 'yellow', updated: false, },
  { color: 'purple', updated: false, },
];
// since this function doesnt depend on state move it outside of
// App; otherwise will be re-created on every render
const RenderCard = (card) => (
  <View style={[styles.card, { backgroundColor: card.color }]}>
    {card.updated && <Text style={styles.updatedText}>UPDATED</Text>}
  </View>
);
export default function App() {
  const [cardIndex, setCardIndex] = useState(0);
  // since cards values can change should be stored in state
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(initialCardState);
  const swiperRef = useRef(null);
  const [swiperKey, setSwiperKey] = useState("swiper-key")
  const updateCard = () => {
    setCards((prev) => {
      const newCards = [...prev];
      newCards[cardIndex].updated = !newCards[cardIndex].updated;
      return newCards;
    });
    // since setting the state isnt enough to get
    // the swiper component to re-render
    setSwiperKey(prev=>prev+getRandomInt(0,10))

  };

  const onSwiped = () => {
    // use the callback version of state setters
    // for better reliability
    setCardIndex((prev) => (prev + 1) % cards.length);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Swiper
        key={swiperKey}
        ref={swiperRef}
        cards={cards}
        renderCard={RenderCard}
        onSwipedLeft={onSwiped}
        onSwipedRight={onSwiped}
        cardIndex={cardIndex}
        infinite
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={updateCard}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Update card</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  card: {
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  updatedText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
  },
  button: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});



Ok, it's working. But I guess it's more costly than just re render the card ? I will try to it on my more complex use case see if it has performance drawback.

import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-deck-swiper';

const cards = [
    { color: 'red', updated: false },
    { color: 'blue', updated: false },
    { color: 'green', updated: false },
    { color: 'yellow', updated: false },
    { color: 'purple', updated: false },
];

export default function App() {
    const [cardIndex, setCardIndex] = useState(0);
    const [swiperKey, setSwiperKey] = useState(Date.now()); // Initialize swiperKey with current timestamp
    const swiperRef = useRef(null);

    const updateCard = () => {
        cards[cardIndex].updated = !cards[cardIndex].updated;
        setSwiperKey(Date.now()); // Change swiperKey to trigger re-render
    };

    const onSwiped = () => {
        setCardIndex((cardIndex + 1) % cards.length);
    };

    const renderCard = (card) => (
        <View style={[styles.card, { backgroundColor: card.color }]}>
            {card.updated && <Text style={styles.updatedText}>UPDATED</Text>}
        </View>
    );

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Swiper
                key={swiperKey} // Change key to trigger re-render
                ref={swiperRef}
                cards={cards}
                renderCard={renderCard}
                onSwiped={onSwiped}
                onSwipedLeft={onSwiped}
                onSwipedRight={onSwiped}
                cardIndex={cardIndex}
                infinite
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={updateCard}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Update card</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    card: {
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    updatedText: {
        position: 'absolute',
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'black',
    },
    button: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 20,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
});

Give this a try; it will update the content on the card.
